# Show that $(A \cap B)$ is subset of $A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm having problems doing this because when I do a membership table, they do not come out to be equal.

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets.

Show that $(A \cap B)$ is subset of $A$.

Comment: What is the meaning of intersection of two sets?

Comment: So you have to show that $x\in A\cap B$ implies $x\in A$, given the fact that $x\in A\cap B\iff x\in A\land x\in B$.

Comment: Sorry what is a 'membership table' and what wants to be equal to what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume $$x \in A\cap B$$

We show that it follows that $x\in A$, and hence $A\cap B \subseteq A$

If $x \in A\cap B$, then by the definition of set intersection, $\,x \in A\,$ AND $\,x \in B.\,$ Hence, $\,x \in A.\,$ We can therefore conclude that $$\;x \in A\cap B \;\implies \;x\in A$$

That is, we have shown that $\;A\cap B \subseteq A$.

---

***Note:*** This is a very simple example of what some refer to as an "element chasing proof". To prove $X \subseteq Y$, you assume $x \in X$, and "unpack" what it means for $x$ to be a member of $X$; if you can show from that, that it must follows that $\;x\in Y,\;$ then you will have shown $\;X \subseteq Y$.

Comment: You start with "Assume..." Assume what? $x\in A\cap B$, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You should not expect them to be equal.  Here is an example:

$A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$

$B = \{3, 4, 5, 6\}$

$A \cap B = \{3, 4\}$

Try looking up the definition of $A \cap B$.  Using that definition, if you assume $x \in A \cap B$ you should have enough information to conclude $x \in A$.  This would then prove that $A \cap B \subseteq A$.